# error while executing source code extracted from executable jar file

Tags: java

I have executable jar file which is running perfectly when i am double clicking on it. but when i extracted the source code from jar file and trying to execute it in eclipse it is displaying the following errors

1. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for `ControlPoint`. Fix the build path then try building this project
2. The type `ControlPoint` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Can anyone please help me out in solving these errors..

Comment: can you share the code/strucure of your project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code is using some `ControlPoint` class that Eclipse cannot find.

Either your forgot to import this class or your project have some dependencies that you need to add to your Eclipse project.

Comment: I have use the java decompiler plugin to extract the source code from jar file and I loaded the complete source code in eclipse heliose but it is not working.. I cant share the code because it is confidential...

Comment: Thanks for your reply vakh and juned ahsan